# How to access url with custom domain

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, appdomain

I am working on project using GWT java on google app engine. i want to use custom domain so i configured my own domain in app engine with help of this docs :- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl
 So i tried to access my app myapp.myapp001.myowndomain.com then i cant access my app but if i access my app myapp.myapp001.appspot.com then i can access my app

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by _i cant access_?

Comment: Thank Igor for your response Cant access means when i enter in browser myapp.myapp001.myowndomain.com then request is not sending to server

Comment: so you have a problem with your local internet or browser? how did you figure it didn't send request? can you you provide debug logs?

Comment: no browser and internet problem if i enter ulr in browser as myapp.myapp001.appspot.com then my app home page display

Comment: please provide an output of `curl -v myapp.myapp001.myowndomain.com`. it's impossible to say anything without knowing real situation

Comment: simply without custom domain i can access my app with myapp.myapp001.appspot.com.  just i want to access my app with custom domain how can i acess my app? myapp.myapp001.myowndomain.com is this url right??

Comment: please provide debug log, as I said its impossible to guess without it

Comment: also, how exactly did you configure this 4th level subdomain? not sure what you mean by this address